# How to open a link automatically in new tab which is containing in external website like quora.com?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, html

How to get a link from a external website like a Quora.com and how to click it automatically which should open in a new browser tab, how to do it using JQuery or JavaScript or Android or iOS.

what are the procedures should i follow.

- Get the link from external website like Quora.com
- click that link automatically using Jquery or Android or JavaScript
  or iOS.
- The clicked link should open in new tab or window

Comment: "Click that link automatically" is pretty much guaranteed to be blocked by the native pop-up blocking in all modern browsers. Only an actual user interaction will open a new tab/window.

Comment: is click action will done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering based on what I understood so far.

In your HTML , you can have one Anchor tag  .

```
<a id="aExternalLink" href="http://colorssoftware.com" target="_blank" ></a>


$(document).ready(function(){
$('#aExternalLink').click();
});
```

This way , this link will be automatically called in a new tab.

if you don't want to solve this by using JQuery. Here is Javascript Code

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
var elem=document.getElementById("aExternalLink");
elem.click();
}
</script>
```

Comment: what should i place in #aExternalLink

Comment: Please check , I just edited my answer, I forgot to assign ID to Anchor

Comment: i placed this code in html file but it is displaying nothing

Comment: What you want to display. Above code will not display anything. It only opens a new link in New Tab once DOM is loaded,                                 
    Did you paste my code after editing? Please paste my code again

Comment: i paste ur code in html file, when open it in browser it is not displaying anything , i want to display web page in new tab

Comment: I guess you haven't added Jquery File. Please check Console.

Comment: i added jquery file

Comment: suppose quora has one url in it's webpage how can i get that url and make click link from that url ,like clicking url in quora

Comment: Can you post that link here, Which you want to open.